# Accidentaly deleted config-6.0.0-kali6-amd64 file

Tags: kali-linux, initramfs

I installed Kali on my Macbook together with MacOS.

After some manipulations on my `\boot` folder on Kali, I accidentally deleted `config-6.0.0-kali6-amd64`.

Updating, i then have

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.0.0-kali6-amd64
grep: /boot/config-6.0.0-kali6-amd64: No such file or directory
```

How do I get back `/boot/config-6.0.0-kali6-amd64` ? I searched on Kali repo and on the web but it may be generated during install.

Comment: This file is indeed generated during installation, I don't think it can be retrieved without reistall. Before you do, consider what's your purpose in dual-booting with Kali, using it as a desktop Linux distro? As a friendly warning - it definitely is _NOT_ one, it's a security professional's toolbox. And it's not in any shape or form newbie friendly. If you're not well-acquainted with Linux environments, you are headed for a heap of headaches. See [Should I use Kali Linux?](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/) in [Kali documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs/).

Comment: No, it’s not generated during installation, it’s part of the kernel package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reinstall your kernel package:

```
sudo apt reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

This will restore the `config` file (which is shipped in the kernel package, not generated at install time).